# PHP forking delay processing

Tags: php, fork

I have a cron job which runs every minute and executes internal cron logic for a multi tenanted application. The PHP script gets each client, their domains and then forks itself and runs under each client "scope" (internal name). See below:

```
<?php

$i = 0;
foreach($clients as $client) {
    $client->get_domains();
    foreach($client->domains as $domain) {
        $threads[$i]['client'] = $client->id;
        $threads[$i]['domain'] = $domain->id;
        $i++;
    }
}

$pids = array();
foreach($threads as $key => $thread) {
    $pids[$key] = pcntl_fork(); 
    if(!$pids[$key]) {
        $start = microtime(TRUE);
        $handle = popen($args[0] . ' --client ' . $thread['client'] . ' --domain ' . $thread['domain'] . ' 2>&1', 'r');
        // $end1 = ~0.001 sec execution time
        pclose($handle);
        // $end2 = ~60 sec execution time
        exit();
    }
}
```

I'm currently migrating load to another server, so have a fresh Ubuntu 11.04 install and set up like the existing machine. There are around 40 domains running on the app, so 40 forks are created within a second.

My issue is that event with each of the forked processes simply returning `TRUE` the processes are taking around 60 seconds.

When dumping `$end1` time, the popen() is taking around 0.001 seconds, as to be expected. However, when monitoring `$end2` the pclose() is taking ~60 seconds.

Watching htop, the processes are visible, but seem to be paused. There are 4 CPU's and 16GB RAM in the VM and load on the server is under 0.1 while running. Running PHP 5.3.6 on Ubuntu 11.10.

I have a feeling that it is something on the OS / PHP config but ulimit is normal and PHP memory limit and max execution time are unlimited. Is there anything else I should be checking?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says, "The pclose() function waits for the associated process to terminate." Your design really doesn't make any sense on many levels. There seems to be no reason whatsoever to use threads or to use `popen`. Is there more code to come that makes these decisions sensible? Because this really looks like an "H-bomb to kill an ant" program. Just use `fork`/`exec`.

Comment: I've switched round popen() and pclose() for an exec() function in place but it doesn't seem to have an impact on the time of execution. Whilst it may not be optimal, it doesn't change the fact that the same code is running on another machine and executes in under 5 seconds, indicating an OS level lock on child processes...

Comment: Since you don't call `pclose` anymore, `pclose` can no longer be taking 60 seconds. What's the new issue exactly?

Comment: The issue is the same - the `exec()` function behaves the same as the `popen()` / `pclose()` - the jobs are spawned with the cron, but they still take ~60 seconds vs 5 seconds on another, less capable machine. Whilst I can't monitor them from PHP now, they are in the OS process tree. I was wondering if there is a setting similar to Apache's `maxrequestsperchild` that may be kicking in.

Comment: What makes you think your issue has anything to do with process creation? It just sounds like your jobs, for some reason, are taking a long time. You need to figure out what they're doing for all that time.